# python - how to unicode whole column

Tags: python, dataframe, unicode

I have a data frame, and I want to Unicode the whole column, would love some help with it.
When I'm doing:

```
history['word_count'] = unicode(history['word_count'])
```

it puts the whole Unicode of all the rows in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
history['word_count'] = history['word_count'].apply(unicode)
```

*but I'm a bit surprised that a column named `word_count` doesn't have integer values*

Comment: It's a dictionary with words and how many times they showed up.

Comment: @TheCrystalShip and what do you expect unicode'ing that to do exactly? Just seems odd that 1) you have a dictionary in a dataframe and 2) that you want to unicode it...

Comment: 1. I want a word counter in each row ( {'hello':2, 'world':1} for hello hello world)
2. Eventually that didn't work for me. I'm having problems with it. Because the data frame is Unicode.